# частное квадратов и как это понимать?

Tags: python

Даны два ненулевых числа. Найти сумму, разность, произведение и частное их квадратов.

Входные данные: ввести два целых числа а и b (1<=a,b<=100).

Выходные данные: вывести сумму, разность, произведение и частное их квадратов с точностью до 3 цифр в дробной части в разных строках.

**Пример входных данных**

```
1 4
```

**Пример выходных данных**

```
5.000

-3.000

4.000

0.250
```

Звучит как элементарная задачка , но для меня не понятно как вдруг частное квадратов стало вдруг 0,250 если квадрат 1 = 1 , а квадрат 4 = 16 --> 1/16 = 0,0625

Comment: скорее всего в примере имелось в виду, что вводили 1 и 2, а "квадраты" относилось как к сумму, разности, произведению и частному

Comment: @Zhihar разве к примеру сумма квадратов 1 и 4 не равна 17? А остальное тоже не сходится

Comment: 1 ошибка тут в одном - ввели 1 и 2, а квадраты тогда будут - `1^2 + 2^2 = 5`, `1^2 - 2^2 = -3`, `1^2 *  2^2 = 4`, `1^2 / 2^2 = 0.250` - в задаче же требуется найти для для квадратов введенных чисел

Comment: @Zhihar ввели 1 и 4 , а не 1 и 2

Comment: мы имеем или 4 ошибки или 1 ошибку (в зависимости от того как вы понимаете условие - т.е. относятся ли квадраты только к частному или нет), если ввели 1 и 4 или 0 ошибок, если ввели 1 и 2 - логично предположить, что в примере сделали ошибку, написав "1 и 4" вместо "1 и 2"

Comment: @Zhihar да спасибо вы правы ошибка была в примере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n, y = (int(x)for x in input().split())

n_num = n ** 2
y_num = y ** 2

n_y_mus_num = [n_num + y_num]
n_y_ris_num = [n_num - y_num]
pros_n_y_num = [n_num * y_num]
chats_n_y_num = [n_num / y_num]


for i in n_y_mus_num:
    print('%.3f' % i)  # 3 знака после запятой

for i in n_y_ris_num:
    print('%.3f' % i)  # 3 знака после запятой

for i in pros_n_y_num:
    print('%.3f' % i)  # 3 знака после запятой

for i in chats_n_y_num:
    print('%.3f' % i)  # 3 знака после запятой
```

да и вправду в примере допустили ошибку не 1 и 4 , а 1 и 2

Comment: Зачем создавать результат в виде списка из 1 элемента и потом пробегать по этому циклом? Почему бы просто не сохранить результат в переменную и напечатать ее?